# Get and querying data MongoDB in Spring

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I'm new in Java and Spring framework, and currently I'm gonna build API service that get the data from MongoDB. I have the db and a collection that I want to display as JSON file when I call it via Swagger.

The collection

[The database name is coba2 and the collection is Datalocationmodel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXPcQ.png)

**The data model**

```
@Document
public class DataLocationModels {
@Id
private String _id;
private String ann_content_category;
private String ann_sub_content_type;
private String ann_emotion;
private List<String> ann_hashtag;
private List<String> ann_keywords;

public DataLocationModels(String _id,String ann_content_category, String ann_sub_content_type, String ann_emotion, List<String> ann_hashtag, List<String> ann_keywords) 

{this._id = _id;this.ann_content_category = ann_content_category; this.ann_sub_content_type = ann_content_sub_content_type; this.ann_emotion = ann.emotion; this.ann_hashtag = ann_hashtag; this.ann_keywords = ann_keywords}

/.. the getter and setters
```

**The repository**

```
@Repository

// Inherit from MongoRepository lib
public interface DataLocationRepository extends MongoRepository<DataLocationModels, String > {

    // Get data based on id
    public DataLocationModels findBy_id(String _id);
```

**The service**

```
@Service
public class DataLocationService {
    @Autowired
    private DataLocationRepository locationRepository;

    // Retrieve operation
    public List<DataLocationModels> getAll() {
        return locationRepository.findAll();
    }
```

The **controller**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/datalocation")
public class DataLocationController {
    @Autowired
    private DataLocationService repository;

    @RequestMapping(value="/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public List<DataLocationModels> getAllDataLocationModels() {
        return repository.getAll();
    }
```

and **my application.properties**

```
spring.data.mongodb.host=localhost
spring.data.mongodb.port=27017
spring.data.mongodb.database=coba2
```

When I open my swagger and try to call all get all the data, why I get none?

Comment: make sure that you use correct import for Document and Id, and make default annotation without param and then try

Comment: also make DataLocationService as interface and create implement class separately, and then use autowired in controller

Comment: I did your suggestions, but I still got none. I wanna make sure that the controller class is have autowired on the implement class of DataLocationService right?

Comment: you just autowired interface DataLocationService in controller, spring will inject that dependency

Comment: ok thank you, i got the data but with response body server error 500 (undocumented). i trace the following error:
 "trace":"org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate..

Comment: Okay got it. I solved it after tracing that there are some structure document int the DataLocationModels that inconsistent with the fields in the MongoDB. Thank you.